# Why marine steel is not always used in cooking applications

Tags: materials, steel, chemistry

What are the main reasons why marine steel such as 1.4404 (316L) grade is not solely used in cooking and kitchen applications? Other than cost possibly? Why other grades such as 1.4301 (304) are so popular in applications dealing with cooking? If the steel comes into contact with strong electrolytes, even with chelates such as citric acid, under hot temperatures, I would assume that marine steel would be superior. But is it just overkill with unreasonable costs.

Comment: Cost? Availability? Profit margin?

Comment: The main reason is cost, and the cost is because the material is more expensive and more difficult to work with. Just on material cost alone, 316 is 300% the price of 304 in small pieces and 130% - 140% in larger pieces.

Comment: I'd guess cookware is optimized for cold forming manufacture process, in particular deep drawing (??). And of course cost. 304 is used when forming and welding are more important and "okay" corrision resistance is acceptable

Comment: 316 is work hardening as hell. Makes it a nightmare to machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain types of *intergranular corrosion* that non-food grade stainless is susceptible to. for use in food handling equipment, extra alloying agents are required to stabilize the grain boundaries. This is why "ordinary" stainless cannot be used to fabricate milk tanks.

Comment: aha, interesting. Does the cheaper 1.4301 (304) grade possibly have these unwanted characteristics? Probably not in general, as it is so popular. But because the manufacturing method is also important, how these two steels compare after laser cutting and sheet metal bending with reasonable bend angles (such as 90 degrees with radius equal to the material thickness)?

Comment: @Imsa 304 is much easier to machine than 316. That is machining though such as on a mill or lathe, not laser cutting or bending. I imagine the difference is less noticeable with laser cutting and bending. Cookwear is probably formed or cast, not machined though. And since we're talking about steel, it's probably formed.

Comment: Chinese 304 is notorious for not being suitable for high end marine components. So I doubt it would be much good for cooking. My best frying pan is a bit of any old iron that as been stamped from a sheet. https://www.solidteknics.com/cookware/aus-ion/26cmfrypan

Comment: @GregLocock Iron pans do work well, but they are non reactive because of the "seasoning" which is essentially polymerized oils on the surface which protects the pan and provides anti stick properties. You can season steel too.